# AWS Lightsail and Ubuntu Pro

Tags: canonical, esm

I have a number of Lightsail instances running individual web applications on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in my organization, and I'm interested in subscribing to Ubuntu Pro to keep security updates going beyond the initial 5 year period. Is there an accepted way to subscribe some number of individual LS instances to Ubuntu Pro? Should I treat them as "Desktops" in the parlance of the Pro configurator? Thanks!